# To create a macro to trace precedents of an indirect function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-indirect

I am trying to create a macro that trace the precedents of an indirect formula. The indirect formula that looks like: indirect(Sheetname, column, row,TRUE). I tried the following code. However it is not working and I don't know why. So if someone can help me that would be great. Thanx in advance!

```
Sub GetCell()
Dim c As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set c = Selection.Parent.Evaluate(Selection.Formula)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    If c.Parent.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then c.Parent.Activate
    c.Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What's your `.Selection`? Is that going to be the activecell?  A cell with the indirect formula? What's your indirect formula look like? You could possibly parse that as a string, to get the data between `'`...

Comment: I want the selection to be the activecell that contains the indirect formula. The indirect formula looks like the following: =INDIRECT("'"&$B$4&"'"&"!"&O$9&$V9,TRUE). Where B4 is the sheetName, O9 column, and V9 the rownumber).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim strFormula As String, strBetweenParenthesis As String, strNewFormula as String
Dim lPos As Long, lNextChar As Long, lStart As Long, lEnd As Long
dim rSource as range

Set rSource = ActiveCell
strFormula = rSource.Formula
strNewFormula = strFormula
lPos = InStr(1, strFormula, "INDIRECT")

If lPos > 0 Then

    Do
        lStart = lPos + Len("INDIRECT")
        lEnd = InStr(lStart, strNewFormula, ")")
        strBetweenParenthesis = Mid(strNewFormula, lStart, lEnd - lStart + 1)
        strNewFormula= Replace(strNewFormula, "INDIRECT" & strBetweenParenthesis, Evaluate(strBetweenParenthesis))
        lPos = InStr(lEnd - Len("INDIRECT" & strBetweenParenthesis) + Len(Evaluate(strBetweenParenthesis)), strNewFormula, "INDIRECT")
    Loop Until lPos = 0

    rSource.Formula = strNewFormula
End If

rSource.ShowPrecedents
rSource.NavigateArrow True, 1
rSource.ShowPrecedents(True)
rSource.Formula = strFormula
```

Comment: When I run the code in excel I get a run-time error "13" mismatch type at line strFormula = Replace(strFormula, "INDIRECT" & strBetweenParenthesis, Evaluate(strBetweenParenthesis)). How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the value of strBetweenParenthesis when you get the error?

Comment: strBetweenParenthesis = "("'"&$B$4&"'"&"!"&O$9&$V9,TRUE)"

Comment: That doesn't look like something that will work in an INDIRECT formula. what is the formula in the active cell?

Comment: The formula I use in the active cell is the following: =INDIRECT("'"&$B$4&"'"&"!"&O$9&$V9,TRUE). Where B4 contains the name of the sheet, O9 the column letter and V9 the row number.

Comment: I solved the time-error, because in the indirect formula I can remove the True statement. The macro works however I don't need to replace the formula but just go to the precedent. Do you also got a solution for that. That would be great!

Comment: I have made some edits to navigate to the precedent and set the formula back to its original state.

Comment: With the new code the line rSource.NavigateArrow(True,1) becomes red so I changed it in rSource.NavigateArrow=true. However it gives a run-time error show 1004 shows up (unable to get the navigateArror property of the range class) for the last 3 lines. And also the ActiveCell with the indirect function is replaced by the precedent reference.

Comment: Sorry, it should be rSource.NavigateArrow True, 1

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much for your help! You were amazing